# TypeScript typed function argument accepts any

Tags: typescript

Here is a TypeScript snippet that compiles just fine (using 1.5.3).

```
function alertNumber(a: number) {
    alert(a + 1);
}
var x:any = "string";
alertNumber(x);
```

How is it possible that a function requesting parameter of a certain type can be called with argument of type `any`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you opt out of type-checking when you use `any` types.

> [Sometimes] we want to opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the 'any' type. - [Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-any)

To avoid troubles with `any`:

1. Use the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option (or turn off `Allow implicit any types` in Visual Studio).
2. Don't use explicit `any` types except where necessary (Ex. `var x: any`)

Comment: Even though I now understand how this works, I still find it strange. Even without the `--noImplicitAny` option I would presume that when I add a type to a function declaration then it will require any caller to pass that type. The meaning of `any` should still be "this can be anything", but you shouldn't just pass an "anything" variable somewhere where a specific type is required.

Comment: @LukasH I see you've programmed in c#. The `any` type currently works like a dynamic variable in c# (ex. `dynamic str = "asdf"; int num = str;` is ok). So like how you should avoid dynamic types in c#, I would recommend avoiding `any` types in TypeScript.

Comment: I understand your point, but it's hard to avoid `any` when you're converting existing javascript project to typescript. For this kind of workflow turning on `--noImplicitAny` is not an option as it would need a rewrite of the whole code base. The `any` I would like to have is an object that can have any properties, but you can't pass it anywhere where a certain type is requested.

Comment: @LukasH I opened up [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4524).