# Why does typescript allow any to be used as interface

Tags: typescript

We are using typescript for one of our larger project and we ran into a bug due to the fact that typescript allows any to be passed when expecting an interface.

Why does typescript allow this or is there a setting that i missed.

The following code sample compiles correctly

```
interface IInterface{
    InterfaceProperty:string;
}

var prop:any = "2000";

function DoStuff(a:IInterface)
{
    var x = a.InterfaceProperty;
}

// Why am i allowed to pass any as an interface?
DoStuff(prop);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> **Any**
>
> We may need to describe the type of variables that we do not know when we are writing an application. These values may come from dynamic content, e.g. from the user or a 3rd party library. In these cases, we want to opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks. To do so, we label these with the any type:

In short with `any`, you **opt-out** of type-checking

Comment: Of course... we will need to turn on --noImplicitAny and make sure people don't use any. In my mental image any was like Object in C#, however its more like dynamic in C#. Thanks. Simmilar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227277/typescript-typed-function-argument-accepts-any